# Pauling's equation on the relationship between Electronegativity and Percentage Ionic Character

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In Paulings eqn:

$$ \%~\ce{ionic~character} = \left[ 1−e^{−(Δχ/2)^2}\right] \times 100$$

What is $e$?

I for the love of me can't find it anywhere

Comment: Related to the answer: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27535/find-percentage-ionic-character-if-electronegativity-is-given/27571#27571

Answer (score 5):

'e' is a [natural exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), so not an actual measurement.

The equation is correctly written as:

% Ionic character $= (1 − e^{−(\frac{Δχ}{2})^2})×100$

where the $−(\frac{Δχ}{2})^2$ term is raised as a power of the natural exponent 'e'.

Source: The University of the West Indies page [Lecture 3. Polarizability](http://wwwchem.uwimona.edu.jm/courses/CHEM1902/IC10K_MG_Fajans.html), you'll need to scroll down the page a bit to the section labelled 'Bond character based on electronegativity differences'.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I thought. just needed some confirmation. That lecture is exactly what I used